# the base argument of std::stoi

Tags: c++, string, c++11, atoi, strtol

The `stoi` function of c++ is defined as:

```
int stoi(const std::string& str, std::size_t* pos = 0, int base = 10);
```

as you can see, the `base` argument is defaulted as `10`, so by default it could only handle decimal numbers. By setting `base` to `0`, it could handle numbers by their prefixes. This is same behavior as `strtol`, so why is the default value being set to `10`, rather than `0`?

Comment: Possibly because by default they wanted `stoi("000123456")` to yield a decimal number (just trim the leading zeros) instead of making it an octal value with the leading zeros trimmed off.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wrote the proposal that added these functions. The goal of the various `stoX` conversion functions was to provide **simple** conversions. Base 10 is by far the most common usage, and ought to be the simplest, hence the default. Base 0 would lead to many beginner's questions about why converting the string `"010"` doesn't produce 10. You can see this if you read enough questions on Stackoverflow -- many beginners are confused about the rules for literal constants, and expect `int x = 010;` to initialize `x` to 10.